# Select all Checkboxes, appears selected, but are not

Tags: asp.net, .net, checkbox

I'm having a strange problem, I've made a Select all checkbox, that mark as selected a lot of checkboxes.

This is the `CheckedChanged` event

```
protected void chkSelecionaTodasOcorrencias_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chk_selecionaTodasOcorrencias.Checked)
        {
            foreach (ListItem c in chkBox_TiposOcorrencia.Items)
            {
                c.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ListItem c in chkBox_TiposOcorrencia.Items)
            {
                c.Selected = false;
            }
        }
        chkBox_TiposOcorrencia.DataBind();
    }
```

It checks all checkboxes, or uncheck all.

Then I Have another method that insert all checkedboxes in a list.

```
private List<int> insertItensInListIntegers(ListItemCollection itens)
    {
        int value = 0;
        List<int> queryItens = new List<int>();

        foreach (ListItem c in itens)
        {
            if (c.Selected) //<-- Here i'm getting false
            {
                tiposOcorrencias.TryGetValue(c.Text, out value);
                queryItens.Add(value);
            }
        }
        return queryItens;

    }
```

The value informed in parameter is: `chkBox_TiposOcorrencia.Items`

At screen all checkboxes are cheched, but when I try debug, the `c.Selected` value is `false`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are filling the drop down in the page load, be carefull that you are using `!IsPostBack`

Comment: I think that exactly here my problem... I debug again and found the Itens with true, and after with false, but what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like Freak_Droid was describing in his comment, if you are loading your checkboxes on pageload, simply put your code that loads your checkboxes inside an if statement checking for !ispostback.  For example--

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         //here is where you would put any of your code for databinding your checkboxes


        }
}
```